# Formula to find the date given a specific year, month, and day of the week

Tags: calendar-computations

I need a formula to get me to the first or third specified day of the week of the following year.

So, here is the information I am presented. I have a year (y), a month (m) and a day of the week (n). From those variables I need to find date the next year falls on.

For example lets say we start **Wednesday** **1**/3/**2018**. I need a formula to get me to the first Wednesday of January 2019 which, looking at a calendar, is 1/2/2019. This needs to apply to all months and days of the week. A second example, say I start on **Wednesday** **2**/7/**2018**. This formula has to get me to the first Wednesday of February 2019 which, again, looking at a calendar is 2/6/2019.

I have attempted to use Zeller's Rule and refactor to find the date but to no avail. I also found this link:

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20171220175657/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55837.html)

From here, I tried solving for d. But because of the truncation required I could not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, we move ahead by $52$ weeks, i.e., $364$ days to our given date $y$/$m$/$d$.

If this does not involve a leap day,  this takes us to $y+1$/$m$/$d-1$. 
Otherwise, it takes us to $y+1$/$m$/$d-2$. To ensure that we are in the first week of the month, we play with remainders modulo $7$.
Thus our target date is

- $y+1$/$m$/$(d+4\bmod 7)+1$ if $m\le 2$ and $y$ is a leap year
- $y+1$/$m$/$(d+4\bmod 7)+1$ if $m>2$ and $y+1$ is a leap year
- $y+1$/$m$/$(d+5\bmod 7)+1$ otherwise.

Comment: How can I modify this to always accommodate a leap year? This formula needs to handle a project 'n' number of years into the future.